# I'm stuck designing a neural net architecture for my project

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

A few weeks ago I had the idea to write an app that counts the points of players in finished game of go. Instead of using pure computer vision I wanted to use deep learning.

The idea was to translate a picture of a go game into a 19x19x3 px image representing the board position and then count the points. I created all the data for the training. [This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qx5oA.jpg) how an image looks and its corresponding label. So I am training on like 7000 images/labels like this.

I tried out some architectures like multiple conv/pool layers without any FC layers. I am using mostly categorical cross entropy. Sizes of the kernel are 3x3. I played around with different number of filters. Often the training gets like to 60% accuracy and then stops to learn, so no accuracy progress is visible. I am thinking that the architecure is not suitable for my task. Seems like my data is fine although its weird that I always have to cast the data to tf.float32 before training, because tf doesnt let me to use tf.uint8.

Any tips how I could better my architecture for this specific task or maybe even a different approach?

Comment: "counts of players"? aren't there always 2 players?

Comment: counts points of players I meant. edited.

Comment: why does counting the points need a neural network? If it's already an image you get a quick count of all the white and black pixels in a histogram. This is available in openCV.